# snapsvg and requirejs, Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`

Tags: snap.svg

I'm using require and webpack on a project and want to use [snapsvg](http://snapsvg.io/) but when I include it I get the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`

Code is:

```
var Snap = require('snapsvg');
SVG = Snap('#svg');
```

Comment: Please add some code to your question so that we can help to identify the problem.

Comment: @R.Murray I've added the code used when I get the error but it's the use of require that seems to cause the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah the way to do it is to add:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: require.resolve('snapsvg'),
      loader: 'imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0'
    }]
  }
  ...
};
```

in `webpack.config.js` using [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader)

Comment: For those ending up here, [here](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/639) is a fix that works with Webpack 5 and Imports loader 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use snapsvg-cjs, which is actually wrapper writter in snapsvg with common js.

Steps:

```
npm install snapsvg-cjs
```

Import in component like below:-

```
import "snapsvg-cjs";

declare const Snap: any;
```

Now you have Snap object.

Answer (score 1):

To load with **webpack 2.x and 3.x**, install Imports Loader (npm i -D imports-loader), and add the following to your **webpack config**:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: require.resolve('snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js'),
      use: 'imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0',
    },
  ],
},
resolve: {
  alias: {
    snapsvg: 'snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js',
  },
},
```

Then, in any module you’d like to require Snap, use:

```
import Snap from 'snapsvg';
```

**SRC**: [SnapSVG GitHub](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg#webpack)

Comment: I have been using the above for years, without issues. Has anyone got an update for Webpack 4 and imports-loader v1.2?